# Django get field from ForwardManyToOne Descriptor object

Tags: django, django-views

I've got two models here:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    website = models.URLField()
    etc.

    def __str__(self):
        return name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return name

class OrgDetail(models.Model):
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    detail_1 = models.CharField()
    detail_2 = models.CharField()
    etc.
```

I am using generic ListViews to navigate from the organization to the detail entries.

```
class OrganizationListView(ListView):
    model = Organization

class OrgDetailListView(ListView):
    model = OrgDetail
```

What I want now is to add a function (or do something else) to the second view that allows me to display the name of the Organization linked to the OrgDetail entity via the ForeignKey field. Right now I've got:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrgDetailListView,self).get_context_data(
                                                    **kwargs)
        context['name'] = OrgDetail.org 
        print(context)
        return context
```

However, this just gives me...

```
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardManyToOneDescriptor object at 0x03592B50>
```

...rather than the name of the name of the organization.

I'm new to Django and have been banging my head against the wall for hours on this. I'm trying to build a web-based data entry platform. The OrgDetails data points cannot be added to the Organization model as I want to see year-over-year changes for the organization.

Anyway, feel like I've just got a fundamental lack of understanding of some basic principal.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get the field from the class itself, not the instance. If you had an instance of OrgDetail, you could indeed do `orgdetail.org` - but you haven't.

In any case, you don't want to do this here because this is a *List*View, which deals with *many* instances of OrgDetail am of which have their own org value. Instead, do it in the template when you're using through:

```
{% for orgdetail in object_list %}
    {{ orgdetail.detail_1 }}
    {{ orgdetail.org.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: So the design intent is: 

- go to a listview with all organizations (OrganizationListView)
- click the organization
- get directed to a listview of all orgdetails for that organization (OrgDetailListView)

So the intent is that the OrgDetailListView contents would be filtered using the PK of the Organization's link on the previous listview page. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't seem to relate in any way at all to the code you originally posted.

Comment: Okay, well then clearly I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for the input, much appreciated.